How do you record a bidirectional stream in Twilio?
I created a phone agent that uses bidirectional streaming in Twilio and now I want to record all incoming calls.
The issue is that there is no documentation on how to do this with bidirectional media streams. I am using the twilio-media-stream-save-audio-file npm package which lets me save audio from a media stream to a wav file but as the documentation points out:

With bidirectional Media Streams, you can only receive the inbound track.

So, when I set up my recorder to save all media type messages received by my Twilio websocket, it only records the caller's audio and not the audio my server sends back to Twilio (I am using Eleven Labs to generate audio).
Code:
Record Caller Audio:
sendAudio(audio: string): void {
      const audioInput = {
        encodedAudioData: audio,
      };
      this.sendMessage("audio_input", audioInput);

      // Record caller audio
      if (this.callerSpeaking) {
        this.mediaStreamSaver.twilioStreamMedia(audio);
      }
   
  }

Record AI Audio:
async sendAudioToTwilio(audioBase64: string, twilioConnection: TwilioSocket) {

    const twilioMediaMessage = {
      event: "media",
      streamSid: twilioConnection.streamSid,
      media: {
        payload: audioBase64,
      },
    };

    if (twilioConnection.ws.readyState === 1) {
      // Record AI audio
      if (this.aiSpeaking && !this.callerSpeaking) {
        this.mediaStreamSaver.twilioStreamMedia(audioBase64);
      }

      twilioConnection.ws.send(JSON.stringify(twilioMediaMessage));
    } else {
      console.error(
        "Twilio WebSocket is not open. Current state:",
        twilioConnection.ws.readyState
      );
    }
  }

My current approach is to record each stream manually as shown above but this leads to the difficult problems of handling overlapping audio and trimming the outbound audio when I use the clear message. In the end, the recording is 80% representative of the phone call but I'd prefer a way to record the exact audio that was heard.
Things That Don't Work

Record Verb: Basically records a voicemail, is not compatible with media streams
Dial Verb with record attribute: This is used to record a normal call, not one that involves media streams


It turns out this is extremely easy. This article has the answer.
When your websocket receives a start message, record the callSid:
const callSid = jsonMessage.start.callSid;
connection.callSid = callSid;
console.log(`CallSid: ${callSid}`);

startRecording(callSid, connection);

Then call the Recordings endpoint with your account ID and the callSid:
// https://help.twilio.com/articles/360010317333-Recording-Incoming-Twilio-Voice-Calls
const startRecording = async (
  callSid: string,
  twilioConnection: TwilioSocket
) => {
  try {
    const twilioAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const twilioAuthToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${twilioAccountSid}/Calls/${callSid}/Recordings.json`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization:
            "Basic " + btoa(`${twilioAccountSid}:${twilioAuthToken}`),
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          RecordingStatusCallback: `https://${twilioConnection.host}/recording-callback`,
          RecordingStatusCallbackEvent: "in-progress completed absent",
        }),
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("Recording started:", data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error starting recording:", error);
  }
};

